# How to store password in AWS Parameter Store

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I am planning to use AWS parameter store to store config for one of the project I am working on it. We are using cloud formation (or CDK) to deploy all the components. That includes parameter store as well.

I have some config which has password and other sensitive fields which I can't put to in version control. How to handle this scenario?

Comment: I would recommend managing your secret data outside of cloudformation. You can avoid committing the secrets to git by using a sensitive build param, but that secret still needs to be fetched from somewhere to be provided as a build param.

Comment: @jordanm can you please shed more lights on this?

Answer (score 2):

Provisioning a SecureString parameter type is not possible in CloudFormation:

> AWS CloudFormation doesn't support creating a SecureString parameter
> type
> See the following link: [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-parameter.html)

But you can reference it securely, using dynamic references which provide a compact, powerful way for you to specify external values that are stored and managed in other services, such as the Systems Manager Parameter Store, in your stack template.

> Use the ssm-secure dynamic reference pattern to specify AWS Systems
> Manager SecureString type parameters in your templates. For ssm-secure
> dynamic references, AWS CloudFormation never stores the actual
> parameter value. AWS CloudFormation accesses the parameter value
> during create and update operations for stacks and change sets.

Check the following link:[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#dynamic-references-ssm-secure-strings)

Answer (score 1):

I would use [AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/integrating_cloudformation.html) to generate the secrets randomly.

```
            #This is a Secret resource with a randomly generated password in its SecretString JSON.
        MyRDSInstanceRotationSecret:
            Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
            Properties:
            Description: 'This is my rds instance secret'
            GenerateSecretString:
                SecretStringTemplate: '{"username": "admin"}'
                GenerateStringKey: 'password'
                PasswordLength: 16
                ExcludeCharacters: '"@/\'
            Tags:
                -
                Key: AppName
                Value: MyApp
```

And would further export the same into [AWS Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-parameter.html) using a policy attached and later on access them using static or [dyanmic reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html).

The best would be to take your secrets management out of Cloudformation as suggested by @jordanm.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at AWS Secrets Manage for this use case. If you are implementing your solution in Java, see this Github URL:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/secretsmanager